# Can't use python json.loads to turn json string into dictionary .TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
This is my json string

"{\"version\":\"1.4.12\",\"name\":\"earmark_parser\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/earmark_parser\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.4.0\",\"name\":\"statix\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/statix\",\"license\":\"ISC\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.1.0\",\"name\":\"nimble_parsec\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/nimble_parsec\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.0.5\",\"name\":\"makeup\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/makeup\",\"license\":\"Unsure (found: BSD, Unrecognized license file content)\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.5.2\",\"name\":\"poolboy\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/poolboy\",\"license\":\"Unsure (found: Unlicense, Apache 2.0, ISC)\"}"
"{\"version\":\"3.1.0\",\"name\":\"poison\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/poison\",\"license\":\"CC0-1.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.2.2\",\"name\":\"jason\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/jason\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"2.5.1\",\"name\":\"recon\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/recon\",\"license\":\"Unsure (found: BSD, Unrecognized license file content)\"}"
"{\"version\":\"0.6.2\",\"name\":\"licensir\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/licensir\",\"license\":\"MIT\"}"
"{\"version\":\"0.1.9\",\"name\":\"castore\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/castore\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"1.2.1\",\"name\":\"mint\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/mint\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"
"{\"version\":\"0.6.4\",\"name\":\"mojito\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/mojito\",\"license\":\"MIT\"}"
"{\"version\":\"0.15.1\",\"name\":\"makeup_elixir\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/makeup_elixir\",\"license\":\"Unsure (found: BSD, Unrecognized license file content)\"}"
"{\"version\":\"0.23.0\",\"name\":\"ex_doc\",\"licenseFile\":\"/home/alan/code/elixir-test/cards/deps/ex_doc\",\"license\":\"Apache 2.0\"}"

with open("check-deps.txt",'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    rst = []
    for json_string in data:
        my_json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        print(my_json_dict["version"])
```

I want to turn it into a dictionary, but it went out an error. TypeError: string indices must be integers, why can't I use json loads to change json string into dictionary

Comment: It looks like you may have JSON-serialized the JSON serialization of a dict.

Comment: The strings provided all work for me in json.loads(). Which one was giving you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting another json.loads() statement will fix your error, this particular data needs to be parsed twice to convert it to a dictionary.

```
for json_string in data:
    my_json_dict = json.loads(json.loads(json_string))
    print(my_json_dict["version"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of the returned variable `my_json_dict`, you can see that is a *string* (after the json.loads) and not a *dictionary* as you expected, that's why you are getting the error.

```py
for json_string in data:
        my_json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        print(type(my_json_dict))
```

So to solve that you need to nest another `json.loads()`, like this:

```py
with open("prueba1.txt",'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    rst = []
    for json_string in data:
        my_json_dict = json.loads((json.loads(json_string)))
        print(my_json_dict['version'])
```